# How do I get a server up and running in WebStorm?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, webstorm

Because of cross domain issues I need to run my code (which is HTML & JS) via a server in WebStorm. None of the instructions I can find are simple and straight forward. Can someone give me an idiots' guide to doing this?

Alternatively, I have got Tomcat up and running in Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to import a non-java project into it. Again, instructions that a bear of little brain can follow would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm comes with a built-in static web server, listening on `localhost:63342`. All you need to do to run your code on it is right-clicking your `.html` file and choosing **Run**.

see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html, *Debugging an application running on the built-in server*